# Join to a table with table name saved on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
    ProjectHistory(
        Id INT, 
        CreatedDate DateTime, 
        CreatedBy INT, 
        TableName  NVARCHAR(100),
        FieldName  NVARCHAR(150),
        Value NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        LookupTableName NVARCHAR(100), 
        LookupTableIdFieldName NVARCHAR(150), 
        LookupTableValueFieldName NVARCHAR(150)
    )
```

This table includes the change history of projects. So it says which field from which table was changed when and by who. If the field which I am tracking the change of, is coming from a look up table, I save the look up table name, ID field name, and value field name (this is a simplified version of the database and actual database has got a slightly different structure).

I don't have any issue with inserting into this table. The problem is when I want to show the data to the user and I want to join with the lookup table to show the look up value instead of ID.

An example of a record in the table:

```
    TableName  FieldName  Value LookupTableName   LookupTableIdFieldName LookupTableValueFieldName
    ---------  ---------  ----- ---------------   ---------------------- -------------------------
    "Project"  "StatusId" 4     "ProjectStatuses" "StatusId"              "StatusName"
```

I wonder what is the best and the most efficient way to query over this table and load the look up table value for the change. For example for the above record I want to show the StatusName (like "Rejected") for StatusId of 4 along with other auditing values like CreatedBy and CreatedDate.

Comment: The simple answer is you can't. You can't use the value of a column to define what table the relevant data is. This means that you have 2 options, neither are "great". The first is using a `LEFT JOIN` to **every** possible table; this is probably going to perform poorly if you have a lot of tables. If you're only going to be getting data from one of the linked tables at a time, then you could you use dynamic SQL instead. This kind of set up, however, screams poor database design, so the best answer is to actually fix the design, rather than trying to write queries to use what you have.

Comment: The only viable way to join to other table is using dynamic SQL based on ProjectHistory table. Anyway your schema design looks like EAV.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As I said this is not the actual schema design and the actual one is a bit different and more normalized. I just wanted to make it simple here. In addition to that there is always a requirement behind the design which I don't think here is the place to discuss that.

Comment: I tried dynamic query before and couldn't find a good solution. I would appreciate if you post your solutions please.

Comment: @Larnu . . . As Larnu points out, there is no great solution.  My recommendation would be a stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you want a comprehensive answer, you're going to need to supply more info. Specifically what you want your SQL to look like, and some decent sample data (in a **consumable** format).

Comment: I don't need a comprehensive answer, one example will do.

Answer (score -1):

It is kind of a pain.  dynamic sql:

```
declare @tc table (id int identity primary key,  tbl varchar(20), lu varchar(20), luv int, col varchar(20));
insert into @tc values ('bid', 'auctionID', 1, 'BiddingPrice');
declare @tbl varchar(20);
declare @lu varchar(20);
declare @luv int;
declare @col varchar(20);
select @tbl = tbl, @col = col, @lu = lu, @luv = luv from @tc where id = 1;
declare @sql varchar(100) = 'select b.' + @col + ' ' +
                            'from ' + @tbl + ' b ' +
                            'where b.' + @lu + ' = ' + cast(@luv as varchar(10));
select @sql;
exec(@sql);
```

Why are you using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for `Value`? That should be an `int`.

Why not just store the actual value in `ProjectHistory` and save yourself a lot of trouble? If someone changes the value in the lookup table then the project history is no longer valid.

Another option is to just have one lookup table with composite key

```
masterlookupVarchar  
id int   composite 
row int  primary key
val varchar(100) not null
```

Comment: [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) is generally advisable when assembling object names into a query.

Comment: @HABO Yes,  agree.

Comment: Thanks, there is more than one lookup table. So dor your answer to work I have to wrap this code in a cursor or something which is not a preferable approach.

Comment: @Bahman Do you have something better?  It is an answer to the stated question.  What happened to you don't need a comprehensive answer?

Comment: Value is nvarcahr (max) because it can hold other values apart from int. It holds every value change on any project field. Performance at the time of inserting the records in this table is more important to me compared to querying the results. That is why I am avoiding an extra database query to fetch the lookup value when inserting records. However if I couldn't find a better way of doing it I have to do as you said @paparazzo

Comment: @paparazzo this is not an acceptable answer as it works only for one lookup table.